# Dart,Flutter : Meaning of const modifier,Isn't Colors.yellow [200] a constant?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget iconOfAnonymousUsers = CircleAvatar(
  radius: 100.0,
  //backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[200],
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      //Center(child: Icon(Icons.person_outline)),
      Text("anonymous",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          )),
    ],
  ),
);
```

The above iconOfAnonymousUsers can have the const modifier,
so I thought it would be better to add it,
and when I added it.

```
const Widget iconOfAnonymousUsers = CircleAvatar(
  radius: 100.0,
  //backgroundColor: Colors.indigo[200],
  backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[200],
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      //Center(child: Icon(Icons.person_outline)),
      Text("anonymous",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          )),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Then I got the following error.
[image]

I don't think there are any non-const components of iconOfAnonymousUsers, but are there any non-const components?
I'm not sure why the error is occurring.

[image]

I'm already getting an error in the above code, isn't Colors.yellow [200] a constant?

Comment: `Colors.yellow[200]` is a function call to `operator []` on `Colors.yellow`.  Dart currently does not have a mechanism to indicate that a function call can and should be evaluated at compilation time, so `Colors.yellow[200]` can be evaluated only at runtime and therefore cannot be `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MaterialColor yellow` is constant but not its underlying color map.
If you take a look inside the implementation of `MaterialColor yellow`, 
 you will find that its color map `<int, Color>{...}` is not const qualified.

```
static const MaterialColor yellow = MaterialColor(
_yellowPrimaryValue,
<int, Color>{
   50: Color(0xFFFFFDE7),
  100: Color(0xFFFFF9C4),
  200: Color(0xFFFFF59D),
  300: Color(0xFFFFF176),
  400: Color(0xFFFFEE58),
  500: Color(_yellowPrimaryValue),
  600: Color(0xFFFDD835),
  700: Color(0xFFFBC02D),
  800: Color(0xFFF9A825),
  900: Color(0xFFF57F17),
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
<int, Color>{
   50: Color(0xFFFFFDE7),
   ...
}
For example, if it is defined as above, it seems that const can be used,and since it does not change at runtime, it can be defined using const, and I feel that it is better to do so. What could be the reason why the developers didn't actually define it using const?
Or is it not possible to use const for the definition in this case?
Isn't it a very important issue?

Comment: Actually, you can define it as `const` by directly using  the `Color` constructor.. `static const Color yellow = Color(0xFFFFF59D)`. There's also a [discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31351) about this 'issue' in flutter github.

Answer (score 0):

By [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialColor-class.html), if you use `Colors.yellow`, it return a `const MaterialColor`. However, when you use `Colors.yellow[200]` or `Colors.yellow.shade200`, it return `Color`, not `const`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Color (0xFFFFFDE7)
Since the values such as etc. do not change at runtime, I feel that defining using const is more advantageous in terms of performance, but isn't it necessary to worry too much?